# How to allow get recursive directory only inside myproject?

Tags: php

I have a little api that return all struture of files via `$_GET['dir'];` parameter.
My project located is

> /var/www/html/myproject/api.php

Inside folder myproject many folders and files.
I'd like forbidden get structure of files outside

> myproject

folder. Could someone give me an example for forbidden any link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

1. `$dir = str_replace('..', $_GET['dir']);`

On *nix:

2. `$dir = $_SERVER['HOME'] . $dir;`

On Windows:

2. `$dir = $_SERVER['HOMEDRIVE'] . $_SERVER['HOMEPATH'] . $dir;`

Don`t forget to filter out unwanted data in $_GET for security reasons.